# PHP string with numbers seperated with spaces to array

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to store a few variables (numbers) that are in a single string, in an array. Like, if I would use something like

```
"1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1"
```

to store every single number in an array, like:

```
numbers[i];
```

I am sure there is a PHP function for this, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use `$numbers = explode(' ', $string);`. This will create an array based on the spaces as a separator.

More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php